# Multithreading in web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript, pyethereum

Is it possible to run concurrent tasks using **web3.js** and an Ethereum client?

For example, say we have the following code to iterate through a number of blocks:

```
var startBlockNumber = 0;
var endBlockNumber = 1000;

for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
        var block = web3.eth.getBlock(i, true);
        if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
          block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
                do_something(e);
          }})
        }
}
```

Is it possible to run the **do_something()** function concurrently so that the code doesn't wait for each transaction to be processed sequentially?

**Edit:**

I want to process each transaction concurrently in a private block chain using a function which may have a high cost in time.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more of what you're trying to achieve? As per the code, you're trying to run the `do_something` function n times where n=transactions.length in a block. According to the conditions in your code, this function gets executed only if a block has transactions.

Comment: I want to run the javascript highlighted above in a browser and execute the function do_something() concurrently on each transaction of each block.