# Asynchronously querying the block chain

Tags: web3js, filters, query

This question is related to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7067/multithreading-in-web3-js) one or [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3475/how-to-query-local-ethereum-blockchain-for-a-specified-transaction) one. There is a tutorial [here](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/1636/tutorial-3-introduction-to-the-javascript-api) that shows some filtering examples but it doesn't get into transaction level granularity. Can we query the block chain by transaction and process specific transactions asynchronously?

For example, this code goes through blocks starting and ending with a given block number and displays each transaction to or from a given address:

```
function getTransactionsByAccounts(myaccount, startBlockNumber, endBlockNumber) {

  console.log("Searching for transactions to/from account \"" + myaccount + "\" within blocks "  + startBlockNumber + " and " + endBlockNumber + "\"");

  for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {

    var block = eth.getBlock(i, true);
    if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
      block.transactions.forEach( function(e) {
        if (myaccount == "*" || myaccount == e.from || myaccount == e.to) {
          console.log("  tx hash          : " + e.hash + "\n"
            + "   nonce           : " + e.nonce + "\n"
            + "   blockHash       : " + e.blockHash + "\n"
            + "   blockNumber     : " + e.blockNumber + "\n"
            + "   transactionIndex: " + e.transactionIndex + "\n"
            + "   from            : " + e.from + "\n" 
            + "   to              : " + e.to + "\n"
            + "   value           : " + e.value + "\n"
            + "   gasPrice        : " + e.gasPrice + "\n"
            + "   gas             : " + e.gas + "\n"
            + "   input           : " + e.input);

            // Do something asynchronously with the transaction:
            call_async_method(e); // <== HOW CAN WE ADD THIS AS A PROMISE?
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

How can we process a transaction asynchronously (as shown in the code)? possibly using promises and the filters defined in **web3.js**.

Comment: what exactly do you mean 'as a promise'? If your method is i.e. saving the transaction to a db or calling a web service with transaction data, i don't see the need to promisify it, as far as I understand promises well -but I doubt that like 10 times a day :-) -.

Comment: Calling a function confirming that a transaction was found by the filter (I plan on iterating through the block chain and process a set of transactions concurrently. The above code works serially but I need a form of parallelism as each transaction may take a possibly lengthy amount of time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no filter provided to parse the confirmed transactions without going through a block first i.e., you can trigger a filter (and execute **call_async_method()**) whenever there is a latest block: `eth.getBlock("latest")`, but there is no such function for a transaction.

That said, if you're operating on a private blockchain (you trust all the nodes) and believe that all the initiated transactions will successfully be added to the blockchain, you can create filters to react upon `eth.pendingTransactions` so that the actions like **call_async_method()** will be performed immediately without waiting for the transactions to get confirmed and added to the blockchain. However, at a later time, you should always check if these transactions are indeed confirmed.

This is not an ideal or recommended solution and contradicts with the fundamental principles of blockchain, but you can test and check if it's suitable for your use case.

**Edit:**
Fast way to scan blocks for transactions on an account. This is an asynchronous scanner with 200 threads: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7184/2460

Source code [here](https://gist.github.com/ross-p/bd5d4258ac23319f363dc75c2b722dd9).

Comment: I haven't used node js. From what I understand it's a back end module (pretty much like php) that runs javascript. This is great for event based and asynchronous programming as it abstracts from dealing with multithreading. I don't know how easily it can be put in a library and distributed in a software project. And also, what happens when a certain call (call_async_method()) takes "too" long (from my understanding node is single threaded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js)

Comment: I'm not sure, but are all functions running in node js asynchronous? It appears so from https://gist.github.com/ross-p/bd5d4258ac23319f363dc75c2b722dd9

Comment: Even I'm not an expert in node.js. Maybe you can post these as separate questions on stackoverflow? You can try using the `Date().getTime()` function to determine how long it's taking for the call.

Comment: The thing is that Javascript, to my knowledge, executes sequentially in the browser, I need a server-like functionality from a node that checks the block for transactions parallelly using Javascript. I'm reading about nodejs as it seems to run everything in pseudo parallel manner (using deterministic scheduling).

Comment: Please post your findings/thoughts.

Comment: I'm now using a contract based approach on storing data into the block chain (using struct arrays similarly to tables in a database).The problem with the transaction based approach is that you cannot synchronize with the data in the transactions' input field (you can read blocks concurrently but not synchronize with the transaction data field of them).